# Identifying who spent more than a certain amount within any 30 day period?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that lists each customer's transactions along with the date they occurred and how much was spent. What I want to do is get a list of all customers who spent £3k or more within any 30-day period.

I can get a list of who spent £3k or more within the *last* 30 days using the code below, but I'm not sure how to adapt this to cover *any* 30-day period. Any help would be appreciated please!

```
select  *
from
        (
        select      customer_id, sum(spend) as total_spend
        from        transaction_table
        where       transaction_date between (current date - 30 days) and current date
        group by    customer_id
        )
where   total_spend >=3000
;
```

Comment: "how to adapt this to cover any 30-day period" -- by replacing `current date` with the desired period end date, may be?

Comment: @mustaccio That would still limit the results to a set 30-day period though, wouldn't it? To clarify what I want: I'm currently writing this on 2nd December. The code I have above should pull any customers who spent over £3k between 2nd November and 2nd December. But I also need to simultaneously pull customers who spent over £3k between 1st November and 1st December, or during any other 30-day period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.
The idea is to calculate running sum of SPEND for last 30 days for each row.

```
WITH TRANSACTION_TABLE (CUSTOMER_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, SPEND) AS
(
VALUES
  (1, DATE ('2021-01-01'), 1000)
, (1, DATE ('2021-01-31'), 2000)
--, (1, DATE ('2021-02-01'), 2000)
)
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID
FROM
(
SELECT 
  CUSTOMER_ID
--, TRANSACTION_DATE, SPEND
, SUM (SPEND) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY DAYS (TRANSACTION_DATE) RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SPEND_RTOTAL
FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE
)
WHERE SPEND_RTOTAL >= 3000
```

Comment: You got the same solution as me.

Comment: Yes, both functions DAYS and JULIAN_DAY can be used to enumerate dates. The only requirement for such a function is continuous enumeration of dates to make RANGES work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUM()` with a window function and a window frame of 30. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    sum(t.spent) over(
      partition by customer_id 
      order by julian_day(transaction_date)
      range between 30 preceding and current row
    ) as total_spend
  from transaction_table t
) x
where total_spend >= 3000
```

For the data set:

```
 CUSTOMER_ID  TRANSACTION_DATE  SPENT 
 ------------ ----------------- ----- 
 1            2021-10-01        2000  
 1            2021-10-15        1500  
 1            2021-12-01        1000  
 2            2021-11-01        2500
```

Result:

```
 CUSTOMER_ID  TRANSACTION_DATE  SPENT  TOTAL_SPEND 
 ------------ ----------------- ------ ----------- 
 1            2021-10-15        1500   3500
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=02e474dc8e30c249c88146b0d73425ba).